# How to Create Custom Action (Very Basic) in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to create a Basic Action on Folder which would just Print some message in Logs in Alfresco

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to my [series of Alfresco tutorials](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series) which includes one on [creating actions](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/actions/tutorial/tutorial.html) (both rule actions and UI actions).

Answer (score 0):

refer this documentation link for creating custom action in document library.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-add-action-doclib.html